# How to prevent python requests from sending stored cookies

Tags: python, session, cookies, python-requests

Python requests in my script automatically insert stored cookies to the request even I don't specify the cookies in the first request to the web page. How can I prevent it or how can I delete the stored cookies or where are they stored?

I have tried to delete all cookies with

```
CookieJar.clear()
```

and

```
cookies.clear()
```

I have also tried to send a normal request without using the session method.

```
import http.cookiejar, urllib.request
import requests

cj = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()
cj.clear()

headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language': 'cs-CZ,cs;q=0.9'
}
s=requests.session()
s.get('https://admin.booking.com/', headers=headers)
r=s.get('https://admin.booking.com/', headers=headers)
s.cookies.clear()
r.cookies.clear()
```

I want to send the same request as from a web browser, without adding stored
cookies. Or delete the stored cookies.

Comment: Use a new session.

Comment: How did you assert that the cookies are stored and sent?

Comment: I can see with r.request.headers() that is is sent in header.

Comment: How can i set new session? I have tried s.session() , but i still get the same cookies in request header.

Comment: Is it possible you are getting redirected and the cookie is set by the server?

Comment: Probably yes, you are right, when i try r.url i get another web address then in the get request.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. I didn't know that python requests automatically response to redirection header. To show history of redirection i have used this code.

```
print(r.history)
for i,response in enumerate(r.history,1):
    print(i,response.url)

print(r.status_code,r.url)
```

Thank you for your help.